# Linq-to-SQL reverse contains

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How would I reverse contains in a Linq-to-SQL query so that I can check if `Title` or `Description` contain any word from my list, something like:

```
var query = context.Shapes.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(words));
```

Here is what I have now but that is opposite from what I need.

```
 List<string> words = Search.GetTags(q);
 //words = round,circle,square

 using(ShapesDataContext context = new ShapesDataContext())
 {
    var query = context.Shapes.Where(x => words.Contains(x.Title) || 

    words.Contains(x.Description));
 }

// Item 1: Title = Elipse , Decsription = This is not round circle
//This should be a match! but words doesn't contain 
//"This is not round circle", only round and circle so no match
```

**UPDATE**

Now I have

```
  var query = context.Shapes.Where(x => words.Any(w => x.Title.Contains(w) || x.Description.Contains(w)))
  int s = query.Count();
```

but now I get exception on `int s = query.Count();` with message "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator." Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: @ThePower Any word from the list

Comment: The `Local sequence...` exception is because of the `words.Any` bit.  LINQ to SQL can't express that in T-SQL. `Title` and `Description` are what?  Strings of delimited tags?

Comment: @jonnyGold No, just regular strings. I want to get items where title or description cointains any of the words from list

Comment: So, you are looking to do a substring match for each word.  Gotcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most efficient but I managed:

```
 List<string> words = Search.GetTags(q);
 using(ShapesDataContext context = new ShapesDataContext())
 {
   IQueryable<Shape> query = Enumerable.Empty<Shape>().AsQueryable();
   foreach (var word in words)
   {
     query = query.Union(context.Shapes.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(word) || x.Description.Contains(word)));
   }
```

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question.  This solution would work.  Don't forget the `Distinct` so you don't get duplicate `Shape`s.

Comment: Does `Search.GetTags(...)` hit the database, too?  Because then you could join on that table and the query will not scale with the number of tags.

Comment: @jonnyGold No, Search.GetTags() just filters user search query of stop words and returns List<string> of important words, this is my hack for Full Text Search in Linq to Sql:)

Answer (score 6):

You want

```
x => words.Any(w => x.Title.Contains(w) || x.Description.Contains(w))
```

Comment: This feels correct but now I get "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator." exception when trying to apply my Pagnition class when calling query.Count().

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. There's not really any way that I can think of around that. If LINQ to SQL can't translate it, then it can't translate it. I think what you've proposed, while not optimal, is fine.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like NOT-IN collection query?

Then this blog post might help

http://introducinglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

HTH

Comment: That article is not applicable to this question.

Answer (score 0):

my solution is using sub query ( sub select)

```
  dim searchTerms as new list of(string) 'search terms here

  dim Result = (From x In DB.items Where 
                    (
                      searchTerms.Count = 0 Or
                      (From z In searchTerms Where x.SearchableText.Contains(z) Select z).Count > 0
                    )
                    Select x).ToList()
```