# Using Intersect I'm getting a Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sequence, local, intersect

I'm using a Linq to SQL query to provide a list of search term matches against a database field.  The search terms are an in memory string array. Specifically, I'm using an "intersect" within the Linq query, comparing the search terms with a database field "Description".  In the below code, the description field is iss.description.  The description field is separated into an array within the Linq query and the intersect is used to compare the search terms and description term to keep all of the comparing and conditions within the Linq query so that the database is not taxed. In my research, trying o overcome the problem, I have found that the use of an in-memory, or "local" sequence is not supported. I have also tried a few suggestions during my research, like using "AsEnumerable" or "AsQueryable" without success.

```
searchText = searchText.ToUpper();
var searchTerms = searchText.Split(' ');

var issuesList1 = (
    from iss in DatabaseConnection.CustomerIssues

    let desc = iss.Description.ToUpper().Split(' ')
    let count = desc.Intersect(searchTerms).Count()
    where desc.Intersect(searchTerms).Count() > 0

    join stoi in DatabaseConnection.SolutionToIssues on iss.IssueID equals stoi.IssueID into stoiToiss
    from stTois in stoiToiss.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join solJoin in DatabaseConnection.Solutions on stTois.SolutionID equals solJoin.SolutionID into solutionJoin
    from solution in solutionJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new IssuesAndSolutions
    {
        IssueID = iss.IssueID,
        IssueDesc = iss.Description,
        SearchHits = count,
        SolutionDesc = (solution.Description == null)? "No Solutions":solution.Description,
        SolutionID = (solution.SolutionID == null) ? 0 : solution.SolutionID,
        SolutionToIssueID = (stTois.SolutionToIssueID == null) ? 0 : stTois.SolutionToIssueID,
        Successful = (stTois.Successful == null)? false : stTois.Successful
    }).ToList();
    ...
```

The only way I have been successful is to create two queries and calling a method as shown below, but this requires the Linq Query to return all of the matching results (with the number of hits for search terms in the description) including the non-matched records and provide an in-memory List<> and then use another Linq Query to filter out the non-matched records.

```
public static int CountHits(string[] searchTerms, string Description)
    {
        int hits = 0;
        foreach (string item in searchTerms)
        {
            if (Description.ToUpper().Contains(item.Trim().ToUpper())) hits++;
        }            
        return hits;
    }
    public static List<IssuesAndSolutions> SearchIssuesAndSolutions(string searchText)
    {
        using (BYCNCDatabaseDataContext DatabaseConnection = new BYCNCDatabaseDataContext())
        {
            searchText = searchText.ToUpper();
            var searchTerms = searchText.Split(' ');

            var issuesList1 = (
                from iss in DatabaseConnection.CustomerIssues
                join stoi in DatabaseConnection.SolutionToIssues on iss.IssueID equals stoi.IssueID into stoiToiss
                from stTois in stoiToiss.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join solJoin in DatabaseConnection.Solutions on stTois.SolutionID equals solJoin.SolutionID into solutionJoin
                from solution in solutionJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new IssuesAndSolutions
                {
                    IssueID = iss.IssueID,
                    IssueDesc = iss.Description,
                    SearchHits = CountHits(searchTerms, iss.Description),
                    SolutionDesc = (solution.Description == null)? "No Solutions":solution.Description,
                    SolutionID = (solution.SolutionID == null) ? 0 : solution.SolutionID,
                    SolutionToIssueID = (stTois.SolutionToIssueID == null) ? 0 : stTois.SolutionToIssueID,
                    Successful = (stTois.Successful == null)? false : stTois.Successful
                }).ToList();

            var issuesList = (
                from iss in issuesList1
                where iss.SearchHits > 0
                select iss).ToList();
                ...
```

I would be comfortable with two Linq Queries, but with the first Linq Query only returning the matched records and then maybe using a second, maybe lambda expression to order them, but my trials have not been successful.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this [Similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951204/linq-to-sql-reverse-contains), I answered my own quetion in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I looked at the similar issue per your link, but I don't see a solution to the local sequence problem on that page.  How did you solve the local sequence issue (a sequence that is not supported in Linq to SQL)?

Comment: In my answer at that link I created Empty Iqeuryable and just did foreach on the words in my list of strings and unioned queryes to search for each word.That solves loacal issue, creating queryes where it search for each string seapratly instead of whole List<string> which is local sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I will attempt that solution.  It may take me a while to figure out the lambda as that is my weak area.  I will let you know.

Comment: I tried the solution you provided, but with the way my Linq Query is setup to supply information to null records, I got stuck in a vortex of null references.  I did find a solution however (below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after more searching more techniques, and trying user1010609's technique, I managed to get it working after an almost complete rewrite.  The following code first provides a flat record query with all of the information I am searching, then a new list is formed with the filtered information compared against the search terms (counting the hits of each search term for ordering by relevance).  I was careful not to return a list of the flat file so there would be some efficiency in the final database retrieval (during the formation of the filtered List<>). I am positive this is not even close to being an efficient method, but it works. I am eager to see more and unique techniques to solving this type of problem. Thanks!

```
searchText = searchText.ToUpper();
List<string> searchTerms = searchText.Split(' ').ToList();

var allIssues =
    from iss in DatabaseConnection.CustomerIssues
    join stoi in DatabaseConnection.SolutionToIssues on iss.IssueID equals stoi.IssueID into stoiToiss
    from stTois in stoiToiss.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join solJoin in DatabaseConnection.Solutions on stTois.SolutionID equals solJoin.SolutionID into solutionJoin
    from solution in solutionJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new IssuesAndSolutions
    {
        IssueID = iss.IssueID,
        IssueDesc = iss.Description,
        SolutionDesc = (solution.Description == null) ? "No Solutions" : solution.Description,
        SolutionID = (solution.SolutionID == null) ? 0 : solution.SolutionID,
        SolutionToIssueID = (stTois.SolutionToIssueID == null) ? 0 : stTois.SolutionToIssueID,
        Successful = (stTois.Successful == null) ? false : stTois.Successful
    };                

    List<IssuesAndSolutions> filteredIssues = new List<IssuesAndSolutions>();

    foreach (var issue in allIssues)
    {
        int hits = 0;
        foreach (var term in searchTerms)
        {
            if (issue.IssueDesc.ToUpper().Contains(term.Trim())) hits++;                        
        }
        if (hits > 0)
        {
             IssuesAndSolutions matchedIssue = new IssuesAndSolutions();
             matchedIssue.IssueID = issue.IssueID;
             matchedIssue.IssueDesc = issue.IssueDesc;
             matchedIssue.SearchHits = hits;
             matchedIssue.CustomerID = issue.CustomerID;
             matchedIssue.AssemblyID = issue.AssemblyID;
             matchedIssue.DateOfIssue = issue.DateOfIssue;
             matchedIssue.DateOfResolution = issue.DateOfResolution;
             matchedIssue.CostOFIssue = issue.CostOFIssue;
             matchedIssue.ProductID = issue.ProductID;
             filteredIssues.Add(matchedIssue);
         }                    
      }
```